# Link refusing to show up

Tags: support, markdown

See my answer here ([How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-a-javascript-array/2450976#2450976)).

I've edited in a link to a wikipedia article which refuses to show up. Can't see anything wrong with this entry?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your original URL (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle) contained an [en dash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ENdash#En_dash) character (Unicode 8211, &ndash;, etc...), and SO's Markdown engine tends to get confused by such characters in URLs.

Fortunately, the link works just as well with a hyphen (-), so I just replaced it.

You might find it helpful that Firefox will automatically escape such characters when you copy the URL out of the address bar, *because* so many sites have problems with them. The escaped form looks like this:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I failed to notice that the dash was a bit funky (copy-pasted the link). Thanks for fixing!

Comment: For completeness sake: the browser used was Safari 4.0.5 which does not seem to automatically escape copy-pasted urls.

Comment: Most browsers don't escape legal URLs. Some (*cough* IE *cough*) won't even reliably escape *illegal* URLs. Firefox tends to be more aggressive than it needs to be, purely because so many users get strung up by simplistic URL-recognition expressions otherwise (the better short-term solution is for sites to stick to non-reserved 7-bit ASCII in their URLs, but the time approaches when sites will have to start accepting more interesting characters...)