# URL not rendering on StackOverflow

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow, markdown, hyperlinks

I've been having trouble with this lately. Can someone tell me what's wrong with my URL syntax in my answer to this question:

[Programming Technique: How to create a simple card game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641329/programming-technique-how-to-create-a-simple-card-game/2653635#2653635)

I've tried:

```
[Knuth-Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm][1]

[1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle
```

Even *this* is not working

```
<http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle>
```

What's wrong with this?

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42345/link-refusing-to-show-up (I have no votes to close here)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because there is Unicode DASH 8211 (\u2013) in the url, which should be url encoded.

You may use normal hyphen or

`http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%e2%80%93Yates_shuffle`

[Knuth-Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%e2%80%93Yates_shuffle)

Comment: First correct answer gets accepted. I did not notice the `-` had a little extra width on it :)

Answer (score 4):

The em slash (`–`)is the problem:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle

Use a simple n slash (the normal one `-`):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle

Wikipedia is smart enough to work with that replacement.

Already fixed it on the post.

Answer (score 2):

Note that [as of recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60211/auto-escape-url-when-entering-with-hyperlink-button-ctrll/82263#82263), when entering a link via the button (or Ctrl-L), characters that could cause problems will automatically be escaped.